# iphone instance / class method issue

Tags: iphone, uiview, uibutton

Okay, so I have a viewController method that has some elements created with interface builder and some I coded myself.

I created a view in the IB...lets call it viewOne. I created a loop that creates buttons (through code) and places them on a separate view (viewTwo). This is done in a class method. However, I want the view I made to be opened everytime one of the buttons is clicked. So I did:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(woogoo:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The woogoo class does the following:

```
+(void) woogoo:(id)sender { 
    //back button
    [self.view addSubview:viewOne]
}
```

However, the program crashes when a button is clicked. I did try making woogoo an instance method but it also crashes in this case too. All I want to do is show viewOne when a button is clicked. Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: What error do you get exactly when you make it an instance method?

Comment: When I make woogoo an instance method.. I get this message in the console:

2010-03-19 00:16:17.258 InstantNavigatore[85979:207] *** +[HomeViewController woogoo:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xc7b8

2010-03-19 00:16:17.259 InstantNavigatore[85979:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[HomeViewController woogoo:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xc7b8'

Answer (score 0):

Instead why don't you hook up an IBAction in interface builder to the button, then you can just put your [self.view addSubview:viewOne]; into that IBAction method.

PS. You're missing a semicolon after [self.view addSubview:viewOne]

Cheers

Comment: I'm not doing it via an IBAction in the interface builder because the buttons i'm creating are constantly being created. Basically, this part of the applications is a "Notifications" section. So when a user created a notification, a new button is made and placed on the screen. I can't really call an IBAction that way.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough info but I'd guess something is wrong with the content of "viewOne" when you are in woogoo.  Add this line just before the addSubview and see what you get on the console:

```
NSLog("woogoo: %@", viewOne);
```

You should see something like this, that matches the type of view and frame you created for viewOne.  If you see (null) or something else well, check how viewOne gets set.

```
<UIView: 0x4519b70; frame = (10 1; 300 43); layer = <CALayer: 0x4519540>>
```

Maybe you could post more info on how/when viewOne is created/initialized.

Answer (score 0):

In `+woogoo:`, you invoke `self.view`. Since it is a class method, `self` is a class too, so `+view` must also be a class method. Did you make it a class method?

If not, you need to make `-woogoo:` an instance method, and also code that calls `-addTarget:…` an instance method, and propagate upwards.